# CIDR First Ip- IpV4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, ipv4, subnet

while assigning CIDR block for subnets created for VPC (Aws cloud) the CIDR block 10.0.2.0/20 overlapping the CIDR block in of other subnet 10.0.0.0/24.
As per my understanding the first ip of CIDR 10.0.2.0/20 will start with  10.0.2.0. So how it is overlapping.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't taking the different mask bits (`20` vs `24`) into account.

CIDR Block `10.0.2.0/20` address range: `10.0.0.0 - 10.0.15.255`

CIDR Block `10.0.0.0/24` address range: `10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.255`

I suggest using a tool like [this](https://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php) to help visualize your CIDR blocks.